# How do I make a long underlined hspace not run off to the page but split into multiple lines?

Tags: spacing, amsart

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title{Title 1}
\maketitle

Please fill in all details here: \underline{\hspace{50cm}} \\

Thank you

\end{document}
```

I would like to make the underline several lines long, but as you can see it is running off the page here. (I put in the `\\` because I want a line break space between the "detail line" and the "thank you" line)

Comment: unrelated to the question of the underline, you should _never_ end a paragraph with `\\ ` as here, it makes TeX scream at you about badness 10000 which is as bad as it can get.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yea, I have several hundred of those every time I compile my document but I don't know what else is equivalent to \\ which would be more proper to use as opposed to it

Comment: It's hard to say what is equivalent to `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph as that is always just completely wrong so you do not want anything equivalent. If you are looking for a style with vertical space between paragagraphs (which is _not_ what `\\ ` does) then use `\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip]` or better a class or package that is set up for such a design)